# Subsampling a text file with a very distinct pattern and extracting rows

Tags: text

I have a data file that includes a large amount of data, 90% of which I don't need. Here is a small peek of it.

```
0.0000  -1.042E-4
0.1000  -1.042E-4
0.2000  -1.042E-4
0.3000  -1.042E-4
0.4000  -1.042E-4
0.5000  -1.042E-4
0.6000  -1.042E-4
0.7000  -1.042E-4
0.8000  -1.042E-4
0.9000  -1.042E-4
1.0000  -1.042E-4
1.1000  -1.042E-4
1.2000  -1.042E-4
1.3000  -1.042E-4
1.4000  -1.042E-4
1.5000  -1.042E-4
1.6000  -1.042E-4
1.7000  -1.042E-4
```

And it goes on and on. The right hand column is of utmost importance to me. The problem is that I only need the data in whole integers of the left hand. So I'd like to simplify the above to:

```
0.0000  -1.042E-4
1.0000  -1.042E-4
2.0000  -2.032E-4
```

Basically what I'm going for is to remove all the data values that aren't whole numbers, like 1.2, 1.3, etc... Is something like this possible on a huge scale? Thanks! I have access to a UNIX environment but would prefer anything on Windows.

Comment: Do you use R or Matlab? Python? We need a language here and it will be easy. Are there ever any decimal values in the hundredths place, or always `.0` to `.9` with 4 extra zeroes?

Comment: Any language, I can figure it out and no there aren't, just .0 to .9, with 4 zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one quick solution that will require a trip to your UNIX env...

```
grep -E "^[0-9]+\.0" datafile.txt > decimated.txt
```

Explanation:

- This searches with the extended `grep`
- for one or more digits  `[0-9]+`
- at the beginning of the line      `^`
- followed by a period and a zero  `\.0`
- in the file `datafile.txt` and
- sends those lines to a file called `decimated.txt` instead of printing them to the screen.

If required, you could modify the search to include all four zeroes after the dot, or to account for spaces before the first digit...

Comment: Thank you so much! I really liked how you included an explanation to your command as well! Can I ask how you learned this? Classes? Experience? Mucking around? I want to get better with all these unix tools, they are all so extremely useful when used properly. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Glad it helped. Regarding learning: in the same way you can chain together commands in the shell using pipes, you can build up your knowledge by learning a few handy commands, and adding subtleties and more commands as you need them. The motivation can come from seeing how simple tools can do seemingly sophisticated things. For me personally, it is built on experience... plus we wrote a book to teach the skills. ;^)